# Angular 6 unable to convert HttpResonse<any> to a class

Tags: angular6

I am new to angular 6.
below code was working fine with previous version but it is failing once converted to HttpClient -> HttpResponse.

```
getTeamMembers(): Observable<TeamMembers[]> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/workusers`;
    return this.authService.AuthGet(url)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

public extractData(response: HttpResponse<any>) {
    const body = response.json();
    return body || {};
}
```

when i try response.json() inside extractData() i get, property json() does not exist on type HttpResonse error.

typeof(reponse) is giving as object

Here is my AuthGet  method:

```
AuthGet(url: string, options?: { observe: 'response' }): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    if (options) {
        options = this._setRequestOptions(options);
    } else {
        options = this._setRequestOptions();
    }
    return this.http.get(url, options);
}
```

Can anyone help me what am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Is `AuthGet()` an observable? If so, you should use a pipe instead of map directly in Angular 6

Comment: But I don't know if that's related to your problem, as I'd expect you to get another error.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` returns JSON already, unlike earlier versions of `Http` where you had to explicitly ask for it.

Here's one way of getting the result and mapping to a class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

class Todo {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
  constructor(raw: any) {
    Object.assign(this, raw);
  }
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  providers: [HttpClient]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  todo: Todo;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    // Tell Typescript the result of this will be of type Todo
    this.http.get<Todo>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .pipe(
        // Create a new class based on the result JSON
        map((data: Todo) => new Todo(data))
      )
      .subscribe((data: Todo) => {
        this.todo = data;
        console.log(this)
      })
  }  
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-to-class?file=src/app/app.component.ts)